# Angular - (TS) A dynamic import call returns a 'Promise'

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular5, angular7

I have a lot of issues in my angular project over 2000..

I dont know what to do.. **what are steps to fix this**?

**I can rebuild project without problems**! But In my visual studio it looks like a horror! :D

Here is the screenshot of issues I have in my visual studio:

[image]

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Location of my tsconfig.json file:

[image]

Comment: where did you place your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez check for my edit

Comment: try to change your `"module": "es2015"` to `"module": "esnext"`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez hmm what about lib it says es2018 is not recognized?

Comment: change this `"target": "es5"` to this `"target": "ESNext"`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I tried but that didn't solve issue, maybe I should separatedly install typescript? :/